# How to create table while getting input is in array format in php

Tags: php, html, arrays

```
[itemObj] => Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [itemName] => Wheel Alignment
        [serviceDetailId] => 25271777034764455
        [masterServiceId] => 1
        [masterServiceAmount] => 830
        [itemStatus] => 1
        [statusStr] => Pending
    )
    [1] => Array(
        [itemName] => Wheel Balancing
        [serviceDetailId] => 25271777034764456
        [masterServiceId] => 2
        [masterServiceAmount] => 725
        [itemStatus] => 1
        [statusStr] => Pending
    )
```

I created a Table in phtml with the above input array. I need to show only `[itemName]` and `[masterServiceAmount]` in the table.

Any one know how to iterate to get the output?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please learn how to use punctuation in English. Use short and focused sentences, not endless flow of words. Otherwise it's very difficult to understand what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for `foreach`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

```
foreach($array['itemObj'] as $data)
{
    $itemName = $data['itemName'];
    $masterServiceAmount = $data['masterServiceAmount'];
}
```

Comment: then show more of your code - not only your array structure

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate your array using foreach or simple for loop.

using foreach:

```
$arr = $somevar["itemObj"];
foreach($arr as $data) {    

}
```

using for:

```
for( $i=0; $i < count($arr); $i++;) {

}
```

if you only need two indexes itemName and masterServiceAmount, you can always update your query to fetch only the required data like -

select itemName, masterServiceAmount from your_table;

You can enclose the foreach/for into a table structure `table` and print the data into `td` using echo